# Powershell script in jenkins pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins-pipeline

I am running a jenkinsfile using multiline powershell to add VMs to domain and dns.

```
pipeline {
agent { label 'slave-windows' }
stages {
    stage('Parameters') {
        steps {
            script {
            properties([
                parameters([
                            string(name: 'VM_NAME', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter the VM you would like to add to Domain.'),
                            string(name: 'IP_ADDR', defaultValue: '', description: 'Enter the IP of your VM.')
                ])
            ])
            }
        }
    }
    stage('domain') {
        steps {
            powershell '''
                \$VM_NAME=\$VM_NAME
                \$DOMAIN="domain"
                \$IP_ADDR=\$IP_ADDR
                \$DNS="adserver"
                \$username="domain\\administrator" 
                \$password="password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
                \$credential=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(\$username,\$password)

                Add-Computer -ComputerName \$VM_NAME -Domain \$DOMAIN -Credential \$credential -Restart
                Enter-PSSession -ComputerName \$DNS
                Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA –ComputerName \$DNS -Name \$VM_NAME -ZoneName \$DOMAIN -AllowUpdateAny -IPv4Address \$IP_ADDR
            '''
        }
    }
}
```

The vm_name and ip_addr is passed by the user on build run.
When I run the build, I get an error that the vm_name variables is null:

```
powershell.exe : Add-Computer : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ComputerName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
At C:\jenkins\workspace\DNS Registration\Add To Domain@tmp\durable-809aaad3\powershellScript.ps1:10 char:48
+                     Add-Computer -ComputerName $VM_NAME -Domain $DOMA ...

+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-Computer], ParentContainsErrorRecordException

+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.AddComputerCommand
```

I am passing the vm_name on build run but for some reason it doesn't seem to pick up the value. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are treating all variables in the `powershell` step method as PS variables, but it seems like you really want `VM_NAME` and `IP_ADDR` to be Groovy variables from the Jenkines Pipeline `params` object specified in the `parameters` directive. Modifying the code to interpolate Groovy variables, and to use the `params` object values arrives at:

```
powershell """
           \$DOMAIN="domain"
           \$DNS="adserver"
           \$username="domain\\administrator" 
           \$password="password" | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
           \$credential=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential(\$username,\$password)

           Add-Computer -ComputerName ${params.VM_NAME} -Domain \$DOMAIN -Credential \$credential -Restart
           Enter-PSSession -ComputerName \$DNS
           Add-DnsServerResourceRecordA –ComputerName \$DNS -Name ${params.VM_NAME} -ZoneName \$DOMAIN -AllowUpdateAny -IPv4Address ${params.IP_ADDR}
           """
```

which will fix the issue in your question.